# Determine password--Looping to find Character--Appending with StringBuilder

Tags: java

```
public class Programming {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );

      int l = 0;
      StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder();

      l = password.length();
      for (l = 1; l < 100; l++) {
         if (l > 0 || l < 100) {
            System.out.println("Your password has the correct length");
         }
      }
      if (l < 0 || l > 100) {
         System.out.println("Your password does NOT have the correct length");
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < 127; i++) {

      }
   }
}
```

I was wondering how I could run a loop to figure out the first character generated by the PasswordGenerator class.  Documentation [here](http://www.technology.heartland.edu/faculty/todds/csci130/assignments/A5_password/doc/index.html) but each character is only a standard ASCII code between 0-127, after that I must append each character to make it into a String. The length of the password is between 0 and 100(above).

Comment: Don't know what that random (;) is doing in the middle of my program, just noticed it...

Comment: Why are you looping through the password length check 100 times?

Comment: Also, I don't see a password generator in your code. You are just testing an empty string every time an dnot setting the password to anything first.

Comment: Hmmm i thought that would keep the length of the password in between 0 and 100, but I guess thats not what it does.

Comment: No. That is checking the length 100 times. Which is redundant because the length will always be 0 since you never set the password to anything. Did you forget to call the password generator class?

Comment: the class that we have is suppose to generate a random password.. But i don't know how to put that in my code exactly, but its in the same folder as my program..

Comment: depends on how the class is defined (static or not, method names, class name), but it is probably something like `password = passwordGenerator.getPassword()`

Comment: I don't see a method in the API doc for generating a password, so I think the assumption should be that when you create a `PasswordGenerator` object, it generates a password automatically. Just add `PasswordGenerator pg = new PasswordGenerator()` and you'll have your (unknown) password.

Comment: When I do that, it says i have private access to the class, and I can't use it..

Comment: You need to call pg.getPassword() to get the password. It seems like the password is properly encapsulated in the passwordgenerator class. (sorry, written from my iPod)

Comment: So I should add PasswordGenerator pg = new PasswordGenerator();, and pg.getPassword(); to my code?

Comment: Actually, looking at the documentation, it looks like there's no way to get the password. But there are a few methods for comparing it witha length. Try one of those to make sure it's the right length.

Comment: I can use matchLength() to use to compare, but i'm not sure where to use it at, or exactly how to use it, I'm a java noob... /:

Comment: How would I go by using that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a loop.

Once you figure out how to call the password generator class to get a value in your password string, just use the following code to get the first character.

```
char firstCharacter = password.charAt(0)
```